# Filepath can not be found

Tags: c#, streamreader

I have a problem with reading a particular file in my C# program.

I am using the following code:

```
string filePath = @"C:\\Användare\\Elev\\Dec22DeathsBySexAndAge.csv";
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                string result = "";
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string line = reader.ReadLine();
                    string[] valuse = line.Split(',');
                    result += valuse[0] + "\r\n";
                }

                tbxOutput.Text = result;
```

When i execute the code i get an error message that says that the file cannot be found. Why can C# not find my filepath?

Does the names of the maps need to be in english or not if you have another language in your computer? I tried changing the names to english but it didn't work. Does anyone know what the problem may be?

Comment: If you use @, you do NOT need to use double slashes.

Comment: @CSharp you do not need double slashes, but they don't harm either

Comment: You are right, works fine with double slashes as well.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the file is on the system your code is running on. Further more make sure the code has reading access to the folders you are trying to access. Since your code hasn't worked with ASCII only we can assume that this isn't a direct cause to it not working

Comment: I assume "Användare" is just the localized display name of the "Users" directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
string filePath = @"C:\Användare\Elev\Dec22DeathsBySexAndAge.csv";
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    string result = "";
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = reader.ReadLine();
        string[] values = line.Split(',');
        result += values[0] + "\r\n";
    }

    tbxOutput.Text = result;
}
```

No need to use double slashes; but works fine with as well. Make sure the file actually exists. There are some special characters in the path.
Could the file be open?

I created this directory and a text file instead and checked if it can be read. Works fine.